render model testure for output Ledwall costum shape
Hi im start looking to blender. and have a question?
hi have a Ledwall custom shape random title post diagonal side etc ,
and I create a 3d.obj model (I use as screen in. some media servers )
Import to blender create some texture ( some hot lava , ice cubes, water recipients, on fire, etc) but now how to render the exact position in my screen (Ledwall/ slice).
How I map the output?
have a pgn.( transparent pattern i use for after effect)
obj with uv map done.
Thanks In advance!

Hello, Andrés, welcome to BSE. You'll have to give us a more general, abstracted, description of this problem, preferably illustrated with embedded images, using the tools provided. You can't assume BSE users understand what  'Ledwall'  or 'Ledwall/slice'means, at all. And, the question would be clearer without extraneous details? (It's presumably irrelevant what the content of your textures is ?)
